# Is it possible to get a file extension without knowing it?

Tags: php, filesystems, file-extension

I have a file called 94bf663a100e848fb599209af8cdc2b5.wmv. I know `pathinfo` will not give me the extension if I just use the name 94bf663a100e848fb599209af8cdc2b5. I believe `glob` is only for checking if a file exists. So is it possible to get a file extension just knowing the file name (94bf663a100e848fb599209af8cdc2b5)?

Comment: hahahaha that is good. I can't believe you were able to pull off that reference so quick.

Comment: Please note that any extensions are part of the file name: you could have files named `foo`, `foo.bar`, `foo.bar.tar`, `foo.bar.tar.gz`, `foo.bar.tar.gz.sig`, and they all refer to different files. (Temporarily ignoring multiply-linked files.) If you don't know any extensions, you don't actually _have_ the filename. This distinction is important, as it is why [Michael](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615039) and Switz's (now deleted) answers don't work for you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the example on the [php glob manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) suggests, `glob` does **not** simply check if the file exists, it returns every file that matches the expression.

Here's a modification of the example on [that page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for your needs:

```
$name = "94bf663a100e848fb599209af8cdc2b5";
$matching = glob($name . ".*");

$info = pathinfo($matching[0]);
$ext = $info['extension'];
```

This assumes there is one (and only one) file with that name (with *any* extension), but you should be able to modify it if the file might not exist, or there might be multiple files with the same name, and different extensions.

Comment: It works rocker. Just what I was looking for pretty much. Each filename is unique so I think glob would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The [`finfo_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.finfo-file.php) function will inspect the byte signature of a file to return its mimetype.  From there, you can mostly deduce the correct file extension.

```
// Adapted from the PHP docs
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Comment: This assumes that the extension matches the mime type. And fails for variants such as `.jpeg` vs `.jpg`. It also requires some type of lookup table with file extensions.

Comment: fileinfo does not work without the extension. I just tested it. $filename=/file1/file2/94bf663a100e848fb599209af8cdc2b5

Comment: fileinfo works no matter what extension a file has or even if the file has no extension. This is actually the preferred way to find/validate the type of a file. While I don't know why you are trying to get the extension, if it's for validation, anything that does not use heuristics to validate the type will open a security hole to the system.

Comment: It is not for validation. I am using fileinfo for validation and I completely agree with you. I do not have the ability to use $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'] to plug in. The file is just sitting in a folder.

Comment: Ok :) just wanted to contribute those cents to make sure.

Comment: Perhaps a difference on Windows? On Linux `finfo_file()` doesn't care if an extension is present.

Comment: Michael I get file does not exist if I plug in $filename=/file1/file2/94bf663a100e848fb599209af8cdc2b5 and I am on a linux machine. Are you doing something different?

Comment: @Scarface Did you quote your filename?  I'm doing nothing different.

Comment: I entered exactly like this `$name = "/file1/file2/94bf663a100e848fb599209af8cdc2b5";

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
echo finfo_file($finfo, $name);
finfo_close($finfo);` The same extension works with glob

Answer (score 0):

The first few characters of the file (binary) will usually give you some kind of hint about what the file type is.

Try it out by opening some binary files (rar, zip, mp3 etc.) in Notepad.

Comment: Yeah but I am trying to get the extension in php in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Try `filetype()` or `mime_content_type()` function in php...
pass the file path it returns the file type.