# How to get a file extension from a file name without extension?

Tags: php, file-extension, fileinfo

PHP: I am uploading image files in a folder with a name of particular format which is like `postid_posttype_postserial.ext` so that while showing particular blog post I would just use this format based on the post id, post type of that post. But problem here is I dont have extension of that file. So here is the actual question, how do I get the extension of a file of which I just know the name(in name.ext) not the extension.

FYI I searched for this and I found few function which returns extensions but you have to pass a full filename that is with extension to get the info about the file.

Comment: Are you trying to get the image type from a filename that has no extension? or does the filename have an extension which you're trying to find?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get a file extension without knowing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615009/is-it-possible-to-get-a-file-extension-without-knowing-it)

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you need to get the **mime type** of the file then do a `switch` statement in PHP. You can get the mime type of the file by:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
$mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $postid_posttype_postserial_file);
finfo_close($finfo);

$mime_types = array(
    'image/gif' => '.gif',
    'image/jpeg' => '.jpg',
    // etc.
);

$ext = array_key_exists($mime_type, $mime_types) ? $mime_types[$mime_type] : false;
echo $ext;
```

Learn more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

**Update 2:** As pointed out by the comment, replacing `switch` to `array` matching is more elegant.

Comment: Yeah we had the same simplier code when I was editing. hahaha